# /etc/nologin message showing for users with the /bin/bash shell defined

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, ssh, shell

I've set /etc/nologin to contain a custom message, so when users
with the /usr/sbin/nologin shell defined in passwd will try to log in, this custom message will appear on their terminal before throwing them out.

Problem is - this error appears for ALL users, even for root (with /bin/bash defined...)

from the nologin man page:

> NAME
>          nologin - prevent unprivileged users from logging into the system
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          If  the  file  /etc/nologin exists and is readable, login(1) will allow
>          access only to root.  Other users will be shown the  contents  of  this
>          file and their logins will be refused.
>
> FILES
>          /etc/nologin

Ideas?

```
Linux mybox02 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: How does your `/etc/passwd` look like?

Comment: @Jakuje root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash and blockeduser:x:1339:1339::/home/blockeduser:/usr/sbin/nologin

Comment: What did you change in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`?

Comment: @Jakuje nothing :[

Comment: can you login at the console as root?  Also, if you're using `nologin` the shell you should put your message into `/etc/nologin.txt` instead, `/etc/nologin` will override the shell for non root users--though perhaps for root users via ssh as well. . . I'm not sure about that part

Answer (score 3):

All is working as expected:

- The source of /usr/sbin/nologin is very small and easy to check: /usr/sbin/nologin expects no parameter, can't be customised and is not related to /etc/nologin.
- /etc/nologin is related to /bin/login. so at login the content of /etc/nologin is displayed, but still allows root to login. So root user can know why nobody can login (More than one person can be root, so a coworker will be informed of why an other coworker did it).

For information, the main "user" of `/etc/nologin` used to be the `shutdown` command when not used with the "now" parameter (eg: `shutdown -r 23:10 "reboot for maintenance"`)  it would put some minutes in advance the /etc/nologin file to prevent users to login before the imminent shutdown. It puts it now in /run/nologin (which is also checked by /bin/login) to avoid problems with a read-only /etc
Then root can still login and run `shutdown -c` to abort it if needed.

The only "misleading" part is the documentation that while not false, doesn't state that nologin will also be displayed for root.

So you'll have to make a small custom program and put it as shell and better not use a shell interpreted one or somebody will find a way to bypass it (with .profile and alike)